# Angular Material Datatables - Data source from Firestore won't paginate

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, datatable, google-cloud-firestore

I've retrieved some data from firestore and formatted it into an Observable array with a type of InvoiceItem.

The data is loading correctly to the datatable, but the paginator won't initialise with the length of the array, which I believe may be due to the data being resolved asynchronously, but I'm not certain.

Is this correct?

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { InvoiceService } from '../invoice.service';

import { Invoice } from '../invoiceModel';
import { InvoiceItem } from '../invoiceItemModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-invoice',
  templateUrl: './view-invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-invoice.component.scss']
})

export class ViewInvoiceComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  userId: string;
  invoiceId: string;
  invoice: Invoice;
  itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<InvoiceItem>;
  items: Observable<InvoiceItem[]>;
  itemsData = new MatTableDataSource<InvoiceItem>();

  tableColumns = [
    'description',
    'quantity',
    'unitPrice',
    'subtotal',
    'taxCode',
    'tax',
    'total'
  ]

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private invoiceService: InvoiceService, private db: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.userId = this.authService.user.uid;

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.invoiceId = params.id;
    })

    this.db.collection('/users').doc(this.userId).collection('/invoices').doc(this.invoiceId).ref.get().then(snapshot => {
        this.invoice = snapshot.data() as Invoice;
    })

    this.itemsCollection = this.db.collection('/users').doc(this.userId).collection('/invoices').doc(this.invoiceId).collection('/items');

    this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as InvoiceItem;
            data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return data;
        })
    })

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getItems().subscribe(data => {
        this.itemsData.data = data;
        this.itemsData.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.itemsData.sort = this.sort;
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, please try to set your pagination and sort options once in ngAfterViewInit callback of your component, and only update the data of data source in your subscription.

Comment: I have tried this before, and again just now, but it doesn't work

Comment: okay, can you provide a plunker or stackblitz with working example of your case to take a look at?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to only be able to get the pagination and sorting work with `.valueChanges()` to the actual collection itself for some reason. Though it works to paginate and to sort the data, you won't be able to retrieve document $keys.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.itemsCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
}
```